# RHEL + kill -9 not really killing the process

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, kill, ps, pid

We have around 85 running process with `lshw`

Since these process increased the CPU load average ,

We tryed to kill them with `kill -9` but without success

```
root      3275  0.0  0.0 131720  8992 ?        D    Sep18   0:03 lshw -xml
root      5894  0.0  0.0 131720  9136 ?        D    Dec04   0:03 lshw -xml
root      6030  0.0  0.0 131720  9148 ?        D    Dec08   0:03 lshw -class storage
root      6203  0.0  0.0 131720  6568 ?        D    Aug27   0:03 lshw -class storage
.
.
.
```

Example

```
kill -9 3108
```

but process still up , and also the same about all process with `lshw`

What are the alternative to kill those pids?

I also seen from post - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407321/is-there-any-way-to-kill-or-end-a-process-in-disk-sleep

with the following comment

*For some time I'm experiencing a problem where processes end up in disk sleep state for a longer period, and dropping caches with echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches gets them out of it most of the time. I don't know why that is, I suspect a multi-core deadlock problem. Maybe it helps in your case, too.*

so dose the cli - `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

can help about my case?